# Getting random number from php file using ajax wont update with new result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am mucking around with what I thought might be a simple thing to do, which is generate random numbers using jquery ajax. I have an index.php that polls generator.php for a random number and the code is as follows

index.php :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({ url:'./generator.php', cache : false, success: function(data){
    document.write(data.foo);
}, dataType: "json"});
}, 3000);   
</script>
```

generator.php  :

```
<?php
$x = rand(10,100);
$array = array(
    'foo'  => $x    
);
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

So this works fine on the first load, it gets the random number from generator.php but after that index.php continues to load but gets nothing at all and the number displayed stays the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is `document.write(data.foo);`. Replace it with:

```
document.getElementById('anId').innerHTML = data.foo;
```

And add an element with id of "anId" in your html document, before that script.

```
<div id="anId"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
$.ajax({ url:'./generator.php', cache : false, success: function(data){
    document.getElementById('anId').innerHTML = data.foo;
}, dataType: "json"});
}, 3000);   
</script>
```

Comment: yes you are right, doing it this way works... cheers CoursesWeb

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate what you're describing with your exact code. It just keeps appending random numbers to the body element. What does your HTML look like?

Also, if you just want a random number between 10 and 100 you can handle this without PHP.

Here's what I came up with:

```
setInterval(function(){
  var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * 90 ) + 10;
  $('body').text(function(i,val){
    return val + random;
  });
}, 3000);
```

Here's a demo:

http://jsbin.com/evOtuqA/2/edit

Comment: Hmmm thats what I was hoping the code would do for me, except I only get the first number generated on the page and then the script reloads continously without ever stopping and returns nothing else. I know I can just use javascript to get a random number but I wanted to try this way as a test before I apply the method to more complex code in generator.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Javascript to generate a random number using:

```
function randomRange(min, max) {
return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
}
```

Alternatively use:

```
setInterval.randomnumber()
function randomnumber(){
$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: ('./generator.php'),
        success: function(data) {return(data)}
    }); }
```